# Push build from Jenkins to Amazon EC2 using Msdeploy.exe

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, msdeploy

I have a Jenkins job that successfully builds my project, now i am trying to push the build to remote `Amazon EC2 server` using the `MsDeploy` command as follows:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -allowUntrusted -source:contentPath="%WORKSPACE%\dist" -dest:auto,computerName="https://ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8172/MSDeploy.axd?site=Default Web Site",username="administrator",password="xxxxxxxxxxx",authtype="Basic",includeAcls="False"
```

This command is working from my local machine command prompt as well as from the Jenkins server command prompt but giving `ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED` when ran as a `Execute windows batch command` build step from Jenkins Job. Below are the error details:

[image]

When i copy the password from the above formatted `Msdeploy` command from the Jenkins console output and try to remote into the respective server, it doesn't log me in. Whereas if i copy the password from else where say like notepad, word etc.. and try to remote into the server, its working. It looks like the problem is with the way Jenkins is formatting the `Msdeploy` command. Should i have to format it in a specific way or is there any specific order the arguments in the command has to be framed ?

I know there are other options like using the publish over ssh plugin in Jenkins, but wondering why it can't be achieved with a simple `Msdeploy` command.

Comment: Did this ever get resolved? Did you find a solution to this problem because I'm encountering something similar.

Comment: I couldn't get this working after trying many times. The way i am doing this now is using Publish over CIFS plugin from Jenkins. Not a great way to do but works.